# MATLAB - Get every N elements in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I want to get every group of 4
so the result is as such

```
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
```

I do not know how many elements there will be but I know it is divisible by 4

so something like a(1:4) and a(5:8) wont work, I can use a loop, but is there a way to not use a loop?

Comment: `reshape(a,[],2).'` will give you a matrix, each row of which is what you need. Note the transpose *after* reshaping, since MATLAB uses column-major order for arrays.

Comment: Note that for fairly simple questions such as this one, you're welcome to come by [the MATLAB chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave). If somebody's around, they can likely help you with such smaller issues.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks!

Comment: @AndrasDeak , OP wants to reshape with 4 columns , your reshape reshapes the array to 2 rows, probably just a typo on your part

Comment: @SomeGuy yeah, right. I didn't understand what you meant, first:D Just to be clear for Kevin: yes, the logical choice is `reshape(a,4,[]).'`, the point is that you can let one of the dimensions be determined by MATLAB, and the 4 is the one you know without extra effort. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unknown number of elements in `a` you can use `reshape` you just need to figure out how many rows you will have in the final matrix or (better for your case) the number of columns.

```
a = 1:4*10;
a2 = reshape(a, 4, []).';
```

If you went the rows routine you would do this.

```
a = 1:4*10;
a2 = reshape(a, [], numel(a) / 4).';
```

You just need to be sure that `a` has the proper number of elements.  `numel` simply tells you the total element count.